# Jquery run function from child window in parent window

Tags: jquery, window, parent

I have a popup window and I want to run a function from in the parent window.

In the child I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    parent.$.fn.guestFromPop('Action');
});
```

In the parent I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function guestFromPop(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

The problem is when `parent.$.fn.guestFromPop('Action');` I never see the alert, nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: colorbox is not a child window :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't declare the function `$.fn.guestFromPop`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function guestFromPop(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

...all it does is declare `guestFromPop()`, a function only available inside that `document.ready` handler.  You would need to declare the function you're after instead:

```
$.fn.guestFromPop = function(data) {
  alert(data);
};
```

Though, this isn't really correct either, since it wont be called on a jQuery element, you may want something as simple as :

```
function guestFromPop(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

called by:

```
parent.guestFromPop('Action');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(){
$.fn.TestFunction=function(SampleData)
{
alert(SampleData);
};
});
```

//callable  in other parent page or  iframe
//

```
(function(){
$.fn.TestFunction("sdfsdfsfsfsd");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Figured it out. The problem with your code is that you're not referring to the right window to call the function from. To get from a console to it's parent you'll need 'opener', not 'parent'.

So instead of parent.guestFromPop('Action'), you need to call this:

```
$(self.window.opener.document).guestFromPop('Action');
```

That should refer to the correct function. It worked for me! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
guestFromPop = function(data) {
  alert (data)
}
```

call from iframe:

```
parent.guestFromPop(data);
```