# Button on one iframe to display another iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, show

I have a webpage with two iframes on them:

```
<iframe src="Account.php" class="iframe" id="iframe1"></iframe>
<iframe src="Register.php" class="iframe" id="iframe2"></iframe>
```

On the first iframe, I have a button

```
<input type="button" value="Subscribe" id="btn"/>
```

When I click on this button, I want to show the other, currently hidden iframe '#iframe1', like so: `$('#iframe1').show();`Obviously, the problem is that button and iframe to show are different documents/pages.

Any ideas how I can achieve that if possible without jQuery's .load-function? Thanks!

Comment: If the iframe is from another domain than your site you can't handle any DOM element inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first iframe bind the click event to a function on the main window.

```
// in main window, define the function to show iframe 2
function showFrame2(e) {
   $('#iframe2').show();
}

// in frame 1, bind to that function by traversing to the parent document
$('#btn').on("click", function(e) {
  window.parent.showFrame2(e);
});
```

Untested but it might work.

Comment: ...ah yes, it does work [if I don't surround function showFrame2(e) with document.ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589576/jquery-run-function-from-child-window-in-parent-window), thx!